# Render issue when validation fail with 2 forms on the same page

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

i need to render 2 forms on the same page. To do this, I have 2 actions in my controller, the first one manage the form 1 and render the entire page, the second manage the form 2 and render only this form.

The second action is called in twig with a :

```
{% render (controller("AppBundle:User:secondForm")) %}
```

Both are rendered, both work, excepted when the validation of the form 2 fail. The Controller return the user to the form with form errors but instead of returning to the entire page, it only render the form.

My code look like this :

First action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile/global-page", name="global_page")
 */
public function Global1Action(Request $request)
{
    [.......]

    $process = $formHandler->process($user);
    if ($process) {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'ok');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('an_url'));
    }

    return $this->render('entire_page.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

then Twig global (entire_page.html.twig):

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

{#FlashBags#}
{% include 'components/alert.html.twig' with {'type':'success'} %}

<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12 row">
        <div class="panel panel-profil">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">form 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="{{ path('global_page') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal text-center">
                    {{ form_widget(form) }}
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-main button-sm">Go</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% render (controller("AppBundle:User:secondForm")) %}

{% endblock %}
```

then SecondForm action:

```
    /**
 * @Route("/profile/second-form", name="second_form")
 */
public function secondFormAction(Request $request)
{
    [.......]

    $process = $formHandler->process($user);
    if ($process) {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'ok');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('an_url'));
    }

    return $this->render('only_form2.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

and finaly the second twig (only_form2.html.twig):

```
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
<div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="panel panel-profil" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"> second form panel </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="{{ path('second_form') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-main button-sm">Go 2</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand how to return the user to the entire page (with form errors) instead of rendering only the second form when it's validation fail.

Thank you !

Edit: I found this [post](https://andreas.glaser.me/2013/09/23/symfony2-two-separate-forms-in-one-controller/) which explain how to have 2 forms in one controller. Answer below seems to not work with Symfony 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a multi form action. Something like this :

```
public function multiformAction()
{
    $form1 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($formTypeA, 'form1name')
    ->add('foo', 'text')
    ->getForm();

    $form2 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($formTypeB, 'form2name')
    ->add('bar', 'text')
    ->getForm();

    if('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {

       if ($request->request->has('form1name') {
        // handle the first form
       }

       if ($request->request->has('form2name') {
        // handle the second form
       }
    }

   return array(
    'form1' => $form1->createView(),
    'form2' => $form2->createView()
   );  
}
```

See this [post](http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/06/symfony2-multiple-forms-different-from-embedded-forms/). And this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994563/symfony2-two-forms-in-a-same-page)

Comment: Thank you both, I'll do this in a single action if it's the better way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to send Form request to action where render whole page (`Global1Action`). Not to action where second form is created.

You will need also move both forms handling to `Global1Action`.

To change second form action use this method:

```
$form->setAction($this->generateUrl('global_page'))
```

Or you can implement ajax handling for second form (if you need to keep it's logic in separate action).