# Symfony: Multiple forms on one page

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm stuck with the following problem. I have 3 forms on one page (might be more in the future). when I submit them.. nothing happens (inserting data in the DB) and the other 2 forms get their fields filled in. Might be because they all have a 'name' field? How can I solve this.. so that each forms has is own 'function' and it doesn't interfere with the other forms.

My twig:

```
<div class="box">
            <h2>Form1</h2>
            {{ form_start(form1) }}
            {{ form_widget(form1) }}
            {{ form_end(form1) }}
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h2>Form2</h2>
            {{ form_start(form2) }}
            {{ form_widget(form2) }}
            {{ form_end(form2) }}
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h2>Form3</h2>
            {{ form_start(form3) }}
            {{ form_widget(form3) }}
            {{ form_end(form3) }}
        </div>
```

My controller:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

    $form1->handleRequest($request);
    $form2->handleRequest($request);
    $form3->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form1->isSubmitted() && $form1->isValid() && $request->request->has('form1')) {
        // Do data insert

        //Return to page
    } else if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid() && $request->request->has('form2')) {
        // Do data insert

        //Return to page
    } else if ($form3->isSubmitted() && $form3->isValid() && $request->request->has('form2')) {
        // Do data insert

        //Return to page
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need this `$request->request->has('form1')` since you already have `$form1->isSubmitted()`.  Also check that the submitted forms are valid, they might just not be validating.

Comment: Is there a reason to have all three forms processed by the same method? I did a similar thing by having 3 forms on a single page, but each form had its own controller method.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942808/multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-symfony3) might be helpful.

Comment: If you have more than one form pointing to the same controller/method this would mean that you only need one form with different submit buttons and checks then which button is clicked.

Comment: Removing `$request->request->has('form1'` did indeed help with values gettin in the other forms. form1 gets submitted perfectly, but when I try to submit the other 2.. they seems to point to the first form. They try to insert their data in that query - which is ofcourse not ok.

Comment: The 3 forms have different queries behind it.

Answer (score 7):

I think you don't need to put them all in the same `if`. What you can do is to separate them like this:

```
public function whateverAction(Request $request) {
    $form1 = $this->createForm(...);
    $form2 = $this->createForm(...);
    $form3 = $this->createForm(...);

    $form1->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form1->isSubmitted() && $form1->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($obj1); //of whatever the entity object you're using to create the form1 form
        $em->flush();
    }

    $form2->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($obj2); //of whatever the entity object you're using to create the form2 form
        $em->flush();
    }

    $form3->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form3->isSubmitted() && $form3->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($obj3); //of whatever the entity object you're using to create the form3 form
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('...', [
        'form1'=>$form1->createView(),
        'form2'=>$form2->createView(),
        'form3'=>$form3->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: That's what I did initially, but for some reason when I fill in form 3 and press submit it uses the logic (query) that is behind form 1. Might that because all 3 forms use 'name' in their form?

Comment: @Rafie You have 3 different Entities, right? And for each entity, you have 3 different Forms, right? If yes, then in each of the Forms, the method `getBlockPrefix()` needs to return something like `appbundle_entityname`. And then, each html form, will have a different name, so in this way there is no confusion between the forms. Assuming you are using symfony >= v2.8 (don't remember exactly though from which version on this is valid).

Comment: I don't understand it completely.. I'm totally new to the symfony framework (specially working with forms).

My version is 3.2.6

Comment: @Rafie Then you should first get used a bit more with Symfony. Anyways, entities are table representations in the code. So inside the controller, you have to have something like: `$person = new Person();` where `Person` is the name of the entity. Then, to create the `$form1` form, you'd do `$form1 = $this->createForm(PersonType::class, $person);`. `PersonType` is the form, and the `Person` is the entity which will house the data sent when you press the submit button. In the `AppBundle/Form/PersonType` you need to have the `getBlockPrefix` method.

Comment: Just tried with 2 forms on the same entity, works like a charm.