# How can I keep data previously entered in a Symfony form?

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to keep data that have been entered in fields belonging to a form. I made this form so that the user creates an event. The reason is I included an other form to create a post address, so when the user submit his new address, he retrieves the information previously entered.

Do you have any idea how I can do this ?

(I apologize for all the bootstrap classes in my code.)

**event_create.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}

<div class="events">

<h1 class="display-2 text-center event_form_title">Création d'une nouvelle sortie ou d'une nouvelle activité</h1>

{{ form_start(eventform, {'attr' : {'class' : 'admin_form', 'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

        <div id="eventform">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Type</p>
                {{ form_widget(eventform.category, {'value' : category.id} ) }}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Titre</p>
                {{ form_widget(eventform.title) }}
            </div>                
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Description</p>
                {{ form_widget(eventform.description, {'attr' : {'rows' : '3'}} ) }}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 d-none">
                <p>Langue à partiquer</p>
                {{ form_widget(eventform.spokenlanguage) }}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3" id="dateselection">
                <p>Date</p>
                {{ form_widget(eventform.start.date) }}
            </div>
            <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-end me-sm-3">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <p>Début</p>
                        {{ form_widget(eventform.start.time, {'attr' : {'class' : 'time_event'}} ) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <p>Fin</p>
                        {{ form_widget(eventform.end, {'attr' : {'class' : 'time_event'}} ) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Adresse</p>
                {{ form_widget(eventform.address) }}
            </div>
            <button type="button" onclick="hideAddressButton(); showLocationForm();" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary w-100 mt-4 mb-5" id="showaddress">Créer une adresse</button>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="eventsubmit">
                {{ form_widget(eventform.save, {'label': "Je valide", 'attr' : {'class' : 'btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary w-100 mb-5'}} ) }}
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a href="{{ path('events') }}" class="btn btn-lg backoffice w-100 mb-5"><span class="me-2">&lt;</span> Retour à la liste</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{ form_end(eventform) }}

<!-- Sélectionner/Ajouter une langue -->

{{ form_start(languageform, {'attr' : {'id' : 'languageform', 'class' : 'mb-3'}}) }}
    <p>Langue à pratiquer</p>
    {{ form_widget(languageform.code, {'attr': {'onChange': 'selectLanguage();'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(languageform.name, {'attr': {'class': 'd-none'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(languageform.save, {'attr': {'class': 'd-none'} }) }}
{{ form_end(languageform) }}

<ul class="language_names d-none">
    {% for language in languages %}
        <li class="language_name">{{ language.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul class="language_ids d-none">
    {% for language in languages %}
        <li class="language_id">{{ language.id }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<!-- Créer/Ajouter une adresse -->

{{ form_start(locationform, {'attr' : {'id' : 'locationform'}}) }}
    
    <hr>
    
    <h1 class="display-2 mb-5">Création d'un lieu de rendez-vous</h1>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Nom du lieu</p>
                {{ form_widget(locationform.name) }}
            </div>
            <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-end me-sm-3">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <p>Numéro</p>
                        {{ form_widget(locationform.number, {'attr' : {'class' : 'numbers_address'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <p>Rue</p>
                        {{ form_widget(locationform.street, {'attr' : {'class' : 'texts_address'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-end me-sm-3">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <p>Code postal</p>
                        {{ form_widget(locationform.zipcode, {'attr' : {'class' : 'numbers_address'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <p>Ville</p>
                        {{ form_widget(locationform.city, {'attr' : {'class' : 'texts_address'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Grande ville</p>
                {{ form_widget(locationform.bigcity) }}
            </div>
            <button type="button" onclick="hideBigCityButton(); showBigCityForm();" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary w-100 mt-4" id="showbigcity">Ajouter une grande ville</button>
            <div id="bigcity">
                {% include "front/create/bigcity.html.twig" %}
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center my-5">
                {{ form_widget(locationform.save, {'label': "Enregistrer une nouvelle adresse", 'attr' : {'class' : 'btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary w-100'}} ) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <hr>

{{ form_end(locationform) }}

{% endblock %}
```

**EventController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

class EventController extends AbstractController
{
#[Route('/create/event/category/{id}', name: 'event_create', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function createEvent(
        Request $request,
        Category $category,
        LanguageRepository $languageRepository,
        CountryRepository $countryRepository,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManagerInterface,
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        LocationRepository $locationRepository
    ){        
        $languages = $languageRepository->findAll();

        $language = new Language();
        $languageform = $this->createForm(EventLanguageType::class, $language);
        $languageform->handleRequest($request);
        
        if ($languageform->isSubmitted() && $languageform->isValid()) {
            
            $entityManagerInterface->persist($language);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();
        }

        $connected = $this->getUser();
        $useremail = $connected->getUserIdentifier();
        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $useremail]);

        $location = new Location();
        $locationform = $this->createForm(LocationType::class, $location);
        $locationform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($locationform->isSubmitted() && $locationform->isValid()) {

            $location->setOrganizer($user);

            $entityManagerInterface->persist($location);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();
        }

        $bigcity = new BigCity();
        $bigcityform = $this->createForm(BigCityType::class, $bigcity);
        $bigcityform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($bigcityform->isSubmitted() && $bigcityform->isValid()) {
            
            $entityManagerInterface->persist($bigcity);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();
        }

        $countries = $countryRepository->findAll();

        $country = new Country();
        $countryform = $this->createForm(NewCountryType::class, $country);
        $countryform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($countryform->isSubmitted() && $countryform->isValid()) {
            
            $entityManagerInterface->persist($country);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();
        }

        $event = new Event();
        $eventform = $this->createForm(EventType::class, $event, [
            'addresses' => $locationRepository->findBy(['organizer' => $user])
        ]);
        $eventform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($eventform->isSubmitted() && $eventform->isValid()) {
            
            $event->setOrganizer($user);

            $entityManagerInterface->persist($event);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();

            $participation = new Participation();
            $participation->setParticipant($user);
            $participation->setEvent($event);

            $entityManagerInterface->persist($participation);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('participations');
        }
        
        return $this->renderForm('front/event/create.html.twig', [
            'eventform' => $eventform,
            'languageform' => $languageform,
            'languages' => $languages,
            'locationform' => $locationform,
            'bigcityform' => $bigcityform,
            'countryform' => $countryform,
            'countries' => $countries,
            'category' => $category
        ]);
    }
```

This is my trial with AJAX, but it does not work :

```
<script>
    
    // I bring values entered in form and I send it with Ajax

    inputs = document.querySelectorAll(["input", "select"]);

    function saveDatas(){
 
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        post = {
            title: document.getElementById('event_title').value,
            description: document.getElementById('event_description').value,
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(post));
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299) {
                data = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('click', saveDatas);
    }
    
    // I retrieve values and I entered them in form fields

    languageform = document.getElementById('languageform');

    function retrieveDatas(){

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", false);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299) {
                posts = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
                posts.forEach((post) => {
                    document.getElementById('event_title').value = post.title;
                    document.getElementById('event_description').value = post.description;
                })
            }
        }
    }

    languageform.addEventListener('submit', retrieveDatas);
   
</script>
```

Comment: If an adress is a selection in the event form , you can add a button "add address" where the address selection field. When the user click on , a modal conatins a form to add address appears. When he saves the data you do refresh the selection address field. This can be done with jquery and ajax

Comment: Hello hous. The button "add address" to show new address form is already created. Also, I haven't learnt to use jQuery, I know just Ajax a little. I am doing a projet for the end of my training, so I must use what I learnt.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe there is a way to save data (just entered in fields) with a session for example... and use these datas and give values to each fields.

Comment: So just send the address form with ajax to escape reloading the page and lose data in the event form. Save the address data in the database and refresh address field. I think that always using sessions to fill forms is not a good idea

Comment: Sounds like something you should do in your controller. Can yous hare the code for that?

Comment: Yes, that one is pretty long so I cut the other routes and kept **event_create**.

Comment: I shared my Ajax code. This one doesn't work properly, I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Nico Haase, I tried to set a session in my controller and saved the values from the form in order to use them. I didn't succeed. Do you know how to do it ? If yes, can you give me a clue ?

Comment: I have an example how to post form with ajax and symfony but with some jquery code. If you want I'll post it tomorrow

Comment: Thank you very much hous for the offer. But I will present the project myself, so I wish to be able to explain the code (I really don't know jQuery). So I have been thinking to an other solution : do you think it's possible to pass the datas in the URL ? Let's talk about it tomorrow. :)

Comment: Or maybe it means we have to use ```SessionInterface``` and it's not recommended...

Comment: If you have two forms and you submit one, you will not be able to retrieve the data of the other form in the request. Just one form can be handled

Comment: Thank you hous. I dropped the idea and I decided to display my forms on each page. Moving forwards as long as it works... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand. You have a lot of ways to do it. You can use ajax and javascript ([Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/) is very good and documented on [SymfonyCast](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony/stimulus#play)) to avoid to reload page and create your new address. With Stimulus, your data-controller sent an ajax request, create the new address and update its own content.

You can merge your forms (so all data are sent) with two buttons (so you know which button has been push and which action is triggered. Then in your controller, you create the new address and send back all other data.

A third solution is to [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204375/symfony-multiple-forms-on-one-page). It could help you.

IMO, the first solution is more user friendly.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre Tranchant. This looks interesting... I wish to test the first solution. Do you know how I can include ```{{ stimulus_controller('hello') }}``` in a form on twig file ?