# Several forms on same page

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm working with Symfony 3.1

**My issue** : When I use 2 forms on the same page, only first one works

**Details**:

On my home page, I have a contact form and a comment form.
They are not link, and use differents entities.

They are called via two different renderController.

Forms are created with FormBuilder and submitted via AJAX

I found an article where they say to use createNamedBuilder, but still not working.
If only one form is active, then it works. If both are active, then only the first one works.
The second one send a POST method but do not submit the form

I'm looking for a solution since many days but still nothing.. please HELP !!!

Many thanks

Olivia

view.html.twig

```html
{{ render(controller('BecowoCoreBundle:Workspace:contact', {name: ws.name})) }}


{{ render(controller('BecowoCoreBundle:Booking:bookingList', {name: ws.name})) }}
```

contact Controller :

```html
public function contactAction($name, Request $request)
      {
        $contact = new Contact();
        // $managerContactForm = $this->createForm(ManagerContactType::class, $contact);
        $managerContactForm = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('manager_contact', ManagerContactType::class, $contact)->getForm();

        $WsService = $this->get('app.workspace');
        $ws = $WsService->getWorkspaceByName($name);
        $wsHasTeamMembers = $WsService->getWsHasTeamMemberByWorkspace($ws);

        $emailManager = [];
        $i = 0;
        if($wsHasTeamMembers == null or $this->container->get( 'kernel' )->getEnvironment() != 'prod')
        {
          $emailManager[0] = 'test@test.com';
        }else{
          foreach ($wsHasTeamMembers as $wsHasTeamMember ) {
            $emailManager[$i] = $wsHasTeamMember->getTeamMember()->getEmail();
            $i ++;
          }
        }
        
          // On vérifie que c'est bien le form de contact manager qui est envoyé
        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $managerContactForm->handleRequest($request)->isValid() && $request->request->has('manager_contact')) {
          $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
              ->setSubject('Becowo - Nouveau message d\'un coworker')
              ->setFrom('test@test.com')
              ->setTo($emailManager) 
              ->setBody(
                  $this->renderView(
                      'CommonViews/Mail/Manager-contact.html.twig',
                      array(
                          'name' => $managerContactForm->get('name')->getData(),
                          'email' => $managerContactForm->get('email')->getData(),
                          'subject' => $managerContactForm->get('subject')->getData(),
                          'message' => $managerContactForm->get('message')->getData()
                      )
                  )
              );

          $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

          $session = $request->getSession();
          $session->set('contactManager', 'ok');

          return $this->redirectToRoute('becowo_core_workspace_contact', array('name' => $name));
        }

        return $this->render('Workspace/manager-contact.html.twig', 
          array('managerContactForm' => $managerContactForm->createView(),
            'name' =>$name));
      }
```

Comment controller :

```
public function viewAction(Request $request)
  {
    $WsService = $this->get('app.workspace');
    $ws = $WsService->getWorkspaceByName($request->get('name'));
    $listComments = $WsService->getCommentsByWorkspace($ws);
    $voteAlreadyDone = $WsService->memberAlreadyVoteAndCommentForWorkspace($ws, $this->getUser());

    $comment = new Comment($ws, $this->getUser());
    $formComment = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('comment', CommentType::class, $comment)->getForm();


    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $formComment->handleRequest($request)->isValid() && $request->request->has('comment'))
    { 
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($comment);
      $em->flush();

      $this->addFlash('success', 'Merci ! Commentaire et vote bien enregistrés.');

      return $this->redirectToRoute('becowo_comment', array('name' => $request->get('name')));
    }

    return $this->render('Workspace/comments.html.twig', array('formComment' => $formComment->createView(), 'listComments' => $listComments, 'ws' =>$ws, 'voteAlreadyDone' => $voteAlreadyDone));
  }
```

Submit forms via AJAX :

```js
    // Page d'un WS, envoye le commentaire et le vote en AJAX
    $(function () {
        $("#comment_Envoyer").unbind("click").click(function(){
         $.ajax(Routing.generate('becowo_comment', {name: document.getElementById('wsName').innerHTML}), {
                data: $('#comment-form').serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#CommentResults').html(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                 $('#CommentResults').html("Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer plus tard");
                }
            });
         return false;
        });
    });

    // Page d'un WS, envoye le formulaire de contact manager en AJAX
    $(function () {
        $("#submitContactManager").unbind("click").click(function(){
            $.ajax(Routing.generate('becowo_core_workspace_contact', {name: document.getElementById('wsName').innerHTML}), {
                data: $('#manager-contact-form').serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#modal-body-manager-contact').html(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#modal-body-manager-contact').html("Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer plus tard");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });`enter code here`
```

Comment: Sorry, this site requires that you post your questions in *English* only. Please translate this yourself; someone else translating for you will not help you understand comments and answers, or respond to feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Build your forms as Class. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Create your forms in controller by

```
controller method  $this->createForm(....);
```

as example from Book
public function newAction()

```
{
    $task = ...;
    $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);

    // ...
}
```

pay attention on FORM name!

```
public function getName()
    {
        return 'payments';
    }
```

You MUST have different form name for your forms in the same page!

Do not generate routes in JQuery, just set action for your form in Form class or in Twig and take action from Form directly.

Your ajax code in this case something like this:

```
$("#form_id_first, #form_id_second").submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(e.target);
    $ajax($form.attr('action')) {
        ...some: code,
        data: $form.serialize(),

        ...some: code
    }
});
```

Finally - don'y use for one Form - one Controller.  Create several forms in one controller with different names and render them, or create Twig  Extention, but handle in same place all it!

[Symfony2 : Two forms in a same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994563/symfony2-two-forms-in-a-same-page)

Comment: Hi zalex ! Many thanks for your answer, it's very clear. Let me test and come back to you !

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU so much !!!!!

It's working :)

Carreful, 2 small mistakes in your JS code

$ajax should be **$.ajax**

I had to add 'type: "POST"' even if I setMethod in the controller

Here is the full code if someone face the same issue :

view.html.twig

```html
{{ render(controller('BecowoCoreBundle:Workspace:contact', {name: ws.name})) }}


{{ render(controller('BecowoCoreBundle:Workspace:voteAndComment', {name: ws.name})) }}
```

workspace Controller (both forms have to be in same controller, but can be in different actions)

```html
public function contactAction($name, Request $request)
  {
    $contact = new Contact();
    $managerContactForm = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('manager-contact-form', ManagerContactType::class, $contact)
      ->setAction($this->generateUrl('becowo_core_workspace_contact', array('name' => $name)))
      ->setMethod('POST')
      ->getForm();

    $WsService = $this->get('app.workspace');
    $ws = $WsService->getWorkspaceByName($name);
    $wsHasTeamMembers = $WsService->getWsHasTeamMemberByWorkspace($ws);
    
      // On vérifie que c'est bien le form de contact manager qui est envoyé
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $managerContactForm->handleRequest($request)->isValid() && $request->request->has('manager-contact-form')) {
      $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
          ->setSubject('Becowo - Nouveau message d\'un coworker')
          ->setFrom('contact@becowo.com')
          ->setTo($emailManager) 
          ->setBody(
              $this->renderView(
                  'CommonViews/Mail/Manager-contact.html.twig',
                  array(
                      'name' => $managerContactForm->get('name')->getData(),
                      'email' => $managerContactForm->get('email')->getData(),
                      'subject' => $managerContactForm->get('subject')->getData(),
                      'message' => $managerContactForm->get('message')->getData()
                  )
              )
          );

      $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

      $this->addFlash('success', 'Merci ! Email bien envoyé.');

      return $this->redirectToRoute('becowo_core_workspace_contact', array('name' => $name));
    }

    return $this->render('Workspace/manager-contact.html.twig', 
      array('managerContactForm' => $managerContactForm->createView(),
        'ws' =>$ws));
  }

   public function voteAndCommentAction($name, Request $request)
  {
    $WsService = $this->get('app.workspace');
    $ws = $WsService->getWorkspaceByName($request->get('name'));
    $listComments = $WsService->getCommentsByWorkspace($ws);
    $voteAlreadyDone = $WsService->memberAlreadyVoteAndCommentForWorkspace($ws, $this->getUser());

    // Création du formulaire de commentaires
    $comment = new Comment($ws, $this->getUser());
    $formComment = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('comment-form', CommentType::class, $comment)
      ->setAction($this->generateUrl('becowo_comment', array('name' => $name)))
      ->setMethod('POST')
      ->getForm();


    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $formComment->handleRequest($request)->isValid() && $request->request->has('comment-form'))
    { 
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($comment);
      $em->flush();

      $this->addFlash('success', 'Merci ! Commentaire et vote bien enregistrés.');

      return $this->redirectToRoute('becowo_comment', array('name' => $request->get('name')));
    }

    return $this->render('Workspace/comments.html.twig', array('formComment' => $formComment->createView(), 'listComments' => $listComments, 'ws' =>$ws, 'voteAlreadyDone' => $voteAlreadyDone));
  }
```

Submits forms via AJAX :

```js
$("#manager-contact-form").submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(e.target);
    $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
        data: $form.serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) { 
          $('#contentToRefresh').html(data);  
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#contentToRefresh').html("Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer plus tard");          
        }
    });
});

$("#comment-form").submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(e.target);
    $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
        data: $form.serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#CommentResults').html(data);         
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#CommentResults').html("Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer plus tard");
        }
    });
});
```