# How to integrate more than one form in one controller -> error at submit - Symfony 4.*

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, symfony-forms

I'd like to know how can I put more than one form in one controller?
I did this, see the code below, in my controller which contains 2 forms; 1 to add a horse, and one to add a group of horses:

```
  /*Add a horse*/
  $cheval = new Chevaux();
    $cheval->setParticulier($user->getParticulier());

    $formAddHorse = $this->createFormBuilder($cheval)
         ->add('nom_cheval', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Ajouter'))
        ->getForm();
        $formAddHorse->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formAddHorse->isSubmitted() && $formAddHorse->isValid()) {
        $cheval = $formAddHorse->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($cheval);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_acc');
    }


    /*add a group of horses*/
    $team=new Team();
    $team->setUser($user->getParticulier());

    $formAddTeam = $this->createFormBuilder($team)
      ->add('profession', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Profession::class,
        'choice_label' => 'nom_prof',
        'expanded' => true))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Nouvelle Team'))
        ->getForm();

    $formAddTeam->handleRequest($request);


    if ($formAddTeam->isSubmitted() && $formAddTeam->isValid()) {
        $team = $formAddTeam->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        /*
        * Traitement des données
        */
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_acc');
    }
```

and in the template :

```
<h2> -------Add a horse------ </h2>
{{ form_start(formHorse) }}
{{ form_widget(formHorse) }}
{{ form_end(formHorse) }}
<h2> ------------------------------ </h2>

<h2> -------Add team------ </h2>
{{ form_start(formTeam) }}
{{ form_widget(formTeam) }}
{{ form_end(formTeam) }}
<h2> ------------------------------ </h2>
```

However when I submit one of the forms, it seems that both are send. So it throws the error:

> This form should not contain extra fields

in the form I didn't submit.
The data are send in the database properly, but the error is here and tells me that I am doing something wrong. How do I do to do this the right way?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to accomplish by adding 2 forms to one controller?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994563/symfony2-two-forms-in-a-same-page

Comment: I'd like to give the user the possibility of doing both (add a horse and a group of horses) in one page (their account page) This avoid that they have to go to an other page specifically made for each form. Did I well answered your question Lunin Roman ?

Comment: @Marilou Isn't it better to keep only one group horses form handler, so user can submit one or more horses through it?

Comment: I think @BenjaminKozlowski has answered my question, I have to try more deeply this evening but it seems to work ! Thank you very much Benjamin !

Comment: @LuninRoman yes it could be possible but for other services on the website it would add other problems... But thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I had a case like that once, here is what I did:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProfileForm::class, $user);
$formPassword = $this->createForm(ChangePasswordForm::class, $user);
$form->handleRequest($request);
$formPassword->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // My code to save some things...
    }
}

if ($formPassword->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($formPassword->isValid()) {
        // My code to save some things...
    }
}
```

It works for me but It seems like what you did, at first sight, though.

Maybe it's how you handle it in your template ?

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work either for my case, it is strange that it worked for you and not for me. I added the code of the template, what do you think ?

Comment: As you use `form_widget` it should generate it just fine.
The only difference I see is that I'm not using `SubmitType` class, I added an `input` "manually". I'll do some test to change that with `SubmitType` in my app, to see if that changes something.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried changing my "manual" submit button for a field in my Form class and I have the exact same problem. It seems to be a bug with symfony, I guess, you should report a bug in the symfony github's repo (whit as many details as you can provide). you can do like me and put an `input` just before your `form_end`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `allow_extra_fields` option which can be used like so.

```
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($team, array('allow_extra_fields' =>true))...
```

or like so for `FormType` class

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
        $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        )
    );
}
```

This [option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields) allows you to submit some extra data, not specified in a form builder. As official documentation says

> Usually, if you submit extra fields that aren't configured in your
> form, you'll get a "This form should not contain extra fields."
> validation error.
>
> You can silence this validation error by enabling the
> allow_extra_fields option on the form.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work, i'd say that the problem is worst because it treats every forms, even those I didn't submitted, so symfony tries to puts empty data in the database of the form I didn't submitted... It removes the initial error (this form contains extra field) but not the problem..