# How make two form in same controller [Symfony]

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a probleme, i want two forms in same controller
I have this controller with two forms, but the probleme is the form1 work good ( return new response) but form2 not working ..
what the solution?

```
public function fCandidat($id, Request $request)
{
    $candidat = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Candidat::class)
        ->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(CandidatType::class, $candidat);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        return new Response('form1');
    }

    $defaultData = ['message' => 'Demandes candidats'];
    $form2       = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('demandes', DemandeType::class)
        ->add('send', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();
    $form2->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {
        return new Response('form2');

        return $this->render('index.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView(), 'form2' => $form2->createView()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html

Comment: no, not this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 : Two forms in a same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994563/symfony2-two-forms-in-a-same-page)

Comment: You are trying to fix a bad error IMHO: send forms data to different pages so then you can manage just single request per action.